# Why does pygame crash when I try to plot individual pixels to the screen for an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, pygame

I've been working on a piece of code that compares two images and tells me if they are similar, it also tells me which pixels are different in the image, after this it plots them into a pygame screen so that I can see which parts of the image are moving more clearly. The only problem is that it seems as if pygame cannot handle it or something and it crashes, no errors appear.

code:

```py
import cv2
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

lib = 'Map1.png'
lib2 = 'Map2.png'
lib3 = []
coordenatesx = []
coordenatesy = []

Read = list(cv2.imread(lib).astype("int"))
Read2 = list(cv2.imread(lib2).astype("int"))

counter = 0

for i in range(len(Read)):#y coords
    for j in range(len(Read[i])):#x coords
        blue = list(Read[i][j])[0]
        green = list(Read[i][j])[1]
        red = list(Read[i][j])[2]
        blue2 = list(Read2[i][j])[0]
        green2 = list(Read2[i][j])[1]
        red2 = list(Read2[i][j])[2]
        difference = (blue+green+red)-(blue2+green2+red2)
        lib3.append(difference)
        if difference <= 10 and difference >= -10:
            counter+=1
            coordenatesx.append(j)
            coordenatesy.append(i)


if counter >= (i*j)*0.75:
    print('They are similar images')
    print('They are different by:', str((counter / (i * j)) * 100), '%')
else:
    print('They are different')
    print('They are different by:', str((counter / (i * j)) * 100), '%')

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

while 1:
    screen.fill((20))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
    for l in range(len(coordenatesx)):
        for v in range(len(coordenatesy)):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue, red, green), pygame.Rect(coordenatesx[l], coordenatesy[v], 1, 1))
    pygame.display.update()
```

image1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

Comment: Have you run the code in a debugger to see which line causes the program to exit? Also, a program cannot crash without an error or exit status. Please find what they are and post them.

Comment: Why do you think pygame crashes? Is the application terminated? It the window not responding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygame didn't crash. You know how defining a Pygame window without calling the `pygame.event.get()` method would cause problems, right? Well, when you put

```
    for l in range(len(coordenatesx)):
        for v in range(len(coordenatesy)):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue, red, green), pygame.Rect(coordenatesx[l], coordenatesy[v], 1, 1))
```

into the `while` loop that's supposed to constantly call the `pygame.event.get()` method, you are dramatically slowing down the looping process.

To see this with your eyes, add a `print()` statement into the loop, and see how slow it prints:

```
while 1:
    screen.fill((20))
    print("Looping...")
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
    for l in range(len(coordenatesx)):
        for v in range(len(coordenatesy)):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue, red, green), pygame.Rect(coordenatesx[l], coordenatesy[v], 1, 1))
    pygame.display.update()
```

One fix is to move the `pygame.event.get()` call *into* the nested `for` loop *(as well as the `pygame.display.update()` call if you want to see the updating)*:

```
while 1:
    screen.fill((20))
    for l in range(len(coordenatesx)):
        for v in range(len(coordenatesy)):
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                    pygame.quit()
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue, red, green), pygame.Rect(coordenatesx[l], coordenatesy[v], 1, 1))
            pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [cv2/OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) and [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). Compute the absolute difference of the images with  [`numpy.absolute`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html). Sum the color channels and count the non-zero pixels with [`numpy.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```py
import cv2
import numpy

Read = cv2.imread('Map1.png').astype("int")
Read2 = cv2.imread('Map2.png').astype("int")

diff = numpy.absolute(Read - Read2).astype("uint8")
gray = numpy.sum(diff, axis=2)
count = numpy.count_nonzero(gray)
print(f"{count} / {gray.size}")
```

If you don't want to import NumPy:

```py
diff = abs(Read - Read2)
gray = (diff[:,:,0] + diff[:,:,1] + diff[:,:,2])
diff = diff.astype("uint8")
count = sum([c > 0 for r in gray for c in r])
print(f"{count} / {gray.size}")
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

lib = 'Map1.png'
lib2 = 'Map2.png'

Read = cv2.imread(lib).astype("int")
Read2 = cv2.imread(lib2).astype("int")

diff = numpy.absolute(Read - Read2).astype("uint8")
gray = numpy.sum(diff, axis=2)
count = numpy.count_nonzero(gray)
print(f"{count} / {gray.size}")

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def cv2ImageToSurface(cv2Image):
    if cv2Image.dtype.name == 'uint16':
        cv2Image = (cv2Image / 256).astype('uint8')
    size = cv2Image.shape[1::-1]
    if len(cv2Image.shape) == 2:
        cv2Image = np.repeat(cv2Image.reshape(size[1], size[0], 1), 3, axis = 2)
        format = 'RGB'
    else:
        format = 'RGBA' if cv2Image.shape[2] == 4 else 'RGB'
        cv2Image[:, :, [0, 2]] = cv2Image[:, :, [2, 0]]    
    surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(cv2Image.flatten(), size, format)
    return surface.convert_alpha() if format == 'RGBA' else surface.convert()

diff_surf = cv2ImageToSurface(diff)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    screen.fill((20))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            run = False
   
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(diff_surf, diff_surf.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```